# Transposing Non Adjacent Cells Into the Next Open Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a currently in use inventory sheet that needs to be simplified for data transfer. My thought was to create a new worksheet to minimize the impact of that on the other people that use this spreadsheet. I am attempting to transpose non-adjacent cells from one work sheet to another work sheet in the next available row.  I may have bitten off more than I can chew being a novice with VBA. I was able to find the code below through some searching that is almost working and I amended it to paste into the next open row. The problem I can't seem to get around is that it only transposes the last cell listed in my copyRange. I have attached some screenshots of my source and destination worksheets. It should be noted that the code is only setup with a small test range of 9 cells. In reality the total inventory transfer would be 125 cells, but I can extrapolate from the test size.

Source:

[image: Source worksheet]

Destination:

[image: Destination]

```
Sub RKImport()
Dim copyRange As Range, cel As Range, pasteRange As Range
Set CopyRange = Sheets("Inventory").Range("F2,F3,G3,F4,G4,F7,G7,F8,G8")
Set pasteRange = Sheets("RK").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For Each cel In copyRange
    cel.Copy
    ecolumn = Sheets("RK").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    pasteRange.Cells(1, ecolumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You need to add 1 to `ecolumn` otherwise you are overwriting the last entry each time.

Comment: `ecolumn` is set to last column of row 1. Try replacing the 1 with `pasteRange.row`